# Cross Fade animation

Tags: jquery

I would like the top_content function to cross fade with #test and #test1. Right now the divs #test, and #test1 are using a simple toggle but I would like them both fade out and in at same time.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#test, #test1').hide();
    $('.home').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).html().toLowerCase();
        var $top_content = $('#' + id + ':not(:visible)');
        if ($('.current').length === 0) {
            toggleContent($top_content);
        } else {
            $('.current').toggle(400, function () {
                toggleContent($top_content);
            });
        }
    });

    function toggleContent(top_content) {
        top_content.toggle(400);
        $('.current').removeClass('current');
        top_content.addClass('current');
    }
    $("a.home").click(function () {
        $('.active').not(this).removeClass('active');
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FJ8DV/

Comment: Welcome to SO. Providing a fiddle is great (I wish even some longtime users would). However, please put the code in the question too. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're not getting a "cross fade" effect is this code:

```
        $('.current').toggle(400, function () {
            toggleContent($top_content);
        });
```

You've placed the call to your `toggleContent()` function in the callback that is called *on completion* of the `.toggle()` - so the fade in doesn't happen until the previous fade out is finished. Move that out of the callback and it won't wait for completion thus allowing the animations to happen simultaneously:

```
        $('.current').toggle(400);
        toggleContent($top_content);
```

Also, I assume "cross fade" means the elements should appear in the same place *at the same time*, so you'll need to give them `position:absolute` styling:

```
#top_content div { position : absolute; }
```

Given that you're talking about a cross *fade*, you might like to replace `.toggle()` with `fadeToggle()` as shown in this update to your demo (I've also used a longer delay so the fade is more obvious): http://jsfiddle.net/FJ8DV/1/